# BrowserView rendering below fold of BrowserWindow

Tags: electron

Running into a really strange quirk and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:

**init.js**

```
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const { app, BrowserView, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');

let win = null;

// Init function
const init = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        try {

            // BrowserWindow config
            const config = {
                backgroundColor: '#1d1e20',
                show: false,
                webPreferences: {
                    contextIsolation: true,
                    enableRemoteModule: false,
                    preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
                }
            };

            // Make BrowserWindow frameless (win) or hide titlebar (mac)
            if ('win32' === os.platform()) {
                config.frame = false;
            } else if ('darwin' === os.platform()) {
                config.titleBarStyle = 'hidden';
            }

            // Create BrowserWindow
            win = new BrowserWindow(config);

            // Add listener for BrowserWindow 'ready-to-show' event
            win.once('ready-to-show', () => {

                // Set traffic light position (mac)
                win.setTrafficLightPosition({ x: 10, y: 27 });

                // Show browser window
                win.show();

                // Open DevTools
                win.openDevTools({ mode: "detach" });

                resolve();

            });

            // Load app html
            win.loadFile('./app.html').then(() => {
                // loaded
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            });

        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
};

// Add browser view
const addView = function(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        try {

            // Get window size
            const bounds = win.getSize();

            // Create BrowserView
            const view = new BrowserView({
                backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
                webPreferences: {
                    contextIsolation: true,
                    enableRemoteModule: false,
                    //preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
                }
            });

            view.setBounds({
                height: 375,
                width: 375,
                x: 0,

                // Set "y" coordinate to 0
                // (should be relative to BrowserWindow 0, 0)
                y: 0

                // Set "y" coordinate to a
                // negative integer
                //y: -200

                // Instead, set "y" to inverse of
                // BrowserWindow height
                //y: bounds[1] * -1
            });

            // Load file
            view.webContents.loadFile('./new.html').then(() => {
                
                // Add to BrowserWindow
                win.addBrowserView(view);
                
                // Open DevTools
                view.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: "detach" });

                resolve();

            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            });

        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }

    });
};

// init when ready
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    init().then(() => {
        addView().then(() => {
            console.log("Everything should be working right");
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error loading BrowserView");
            console.error(err);
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error loading BrowserWindow");
        console.error(err);
    });
});
```

Expected result: new BrowserView stacked squarely on top of BrowserWindow at defined width and height, positioned at 0, 0.

Actual result: new BrowserView displayed below the fold, with its "y" coordinate relative to bottom of BrowserWindow. To get BrowserView to show at BrowserWindow 0, 0, must set BrowserView "y" coordinate to (BrowserWindowHeight * -1)

[image: Screenshot]

Edit: P.S.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "init.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^12.0.1"
  }
}
```

**preload.js**

```
(no contents)
```

**app.html**

```
(no contents)
```

**app.js**

```
(no contents)
```

**app.css**

```
(no contents)
```

**new.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body {
            background: #ffffff;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update #1**

Delay call to view.setBounds() by moving inside promise callback of view.loadURL(). No change.

**Update #2**

Further delay call to view.setBounds() by additionally wrapping in setTimeout() with delay of 1000ms. No change.

**Update #3**
By adding the following, the BrowserView does snap to correct 0, 0 position within parent BrowserWindow, but only upon resize event:

```
win.on('will-resize', (event, newBounds) => {
    win.getBrowserViews().forEach((view) => {
        view.setBounds({
            height: newBounds.height,
            width: newBounds.width,
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        });
    });
});
```

**Update #4**
Replaced BrowserWindow.loadFile() and BrowserView.loadFile() calls with .loadURL() using google.com and stackoverflow.com, respectively, to eliminate the possibility of it being something to do with my local files. No change.

**Update #5**
By modifying the **init.js** as follows, it works as expected, however it's not pretty as it "snaps" into position. (Edit: to clarify, BrowserView defined with solid background which I expect to be displayed until .loadURL() completes, unless I've somehow misunderstood the purpose of the backgroundColor property) (Edit: I've just realized that backgroundColor is not a valid property of the BrowserView)

```
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const { app, BrowserView, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');

let win = null;

// Init function
const init = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        try {

            // BrowserWindow config
            const config = {
                backgroundColor: '#1d1e20',
                show: false,
                webPreferences: {
                    contextIsolation: true,
                    enableRemoteModule: false,
                    preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
                }
            };

            // Make BrowserWindow frameless (win) or hide titlebar (mac)
            if ('win32' === os.platform()) {
                config.frame = false;
            } else if ('darwin' === os.platform()) {
                config.titleBarStyle = 'hidden';
            }

            // Create BrowserWindow
            win = new BrowserWindow(config);

            // Add listener for BrowserWindow 'ready-to-show' event
            win.once('ready-to-show', () => {

                // Set traffic light position (mac)
                win.setTrafficLightPosition({ x: 10, y: 27 });

                // Show browser window
                win.show();

                // Open DevTools
                win.openDevTools({ mode: "detach" });

            });

            // Add listener for BrowserWindow 'show' event
            win.once('show', () => {
                resolve();
            });

            win.on('will-resize', (event, newBounds) => {
                win.getBrowserViews().forEach((view) => {
                    view.setBounds({ height: newBounds.height, width: newBounds.width, x: 0, y: 0 });
                });
            });

            // Load app html
            win.loadURL("https://google.com").then(() => {
                // loaded
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            });

        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
};

// Add browser view
const addView = function(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        try {

            // Create BrowserView
            const view = new BrowserView({
                backgroundColor: "#edeef0",
                webPreferences: {
                    contextIsolation: true,
                    enableRemoteModule: false
                }
            });

            // Load file
            view.webContents.loadURL('https://stackoverflow.com').then(() => {

                setTimeout(() => {
                    
                    // Get window size
                    const bounds = win.getSize();
                    
                    // Set BrowserView bounds
                    view.setBounds({ height: bounds[1], width: bounds[0], x: 0, y: 0 });

                }, 1);
                
                // Add to BrowserWindow
                win.addBrowserView(view);
                
                // Open DevTools
                view.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: "detach" });

                resolve();

            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            });

        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }

    });
};

// init when ready
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    init().then(() => {
        addView().then(() => {
            console.log("Everything should be working right");
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error loading BrowserView");
            console.error(err);
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error loading BrowserWindow");
        console.error(err);
    });
});
```

[image: Screenshot]

**Update #6**

<strike>I've come to the conclusion that in current version of Electron (12.0.1), a BrowserView is rendered with equivalent of CSS `position: relative`, but almost immediately thereafter, changed to equivalent of CSS `position: absolute`. Calling BrowserView.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0 }) immediately upon creation of the BrowserView, the BrowserView is actually displayed at { x: 0, y: (BrowserWindow height) }, whereas calling BrowserView.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0 }) within a setTimeout() after a 1ms delay, the BrowserView is actually displayed at { x: 0, y: 0}. I'm not sure why this is, but it seems the fix (tested only on macOS 10.14.6) is as follows:</strike>

```
const view = new BrowserView(...);
const size = win.getSize();
view.setBounds({ height: size[1], width: size[0], x: 0, y: size[0] * -1 });
```

and, on the BrowserWindow:

```
win.on('will-resize', (event, newBounds) => {
    win.getBrowserViews().forEach((view) => {
        view.setBounds({ height: newBounds.height, width: newBounds.width, x: 0, y: 0 });
    });
});
```

**Update #7**

This still feels very unwieldy and I suspect this is not the intended behavior and I still may be doing something wrong. I'm going to leave this question open and hope that someone has a better solution than what I've found.

**Update #8**

Finally figured out that it was my sloppy implementation. After RTFM, adding some promises, and doing things in the proper order, there is no problem.

For educational purposes, I broke it down and reversed my steps to find the source of the problem so I know for future reference. For anyone else who may ever find this and have the same problem -- you must call BrowserWindow.addBrowserView() BEFORE calling BrowserView.setBounds(). That was the problem.

I was calling BrowserView.setBounds() immediately after creating the BrowserView -- at which point it was not added to the BrowserWindow yet, hence why the coords were off. I didn't call BrowserWindow.addBrowserView() until BrowserView.loadFile() resolved.

Comment: what does "below fold" mean? Like the y coord is off?

Comment: @pushkin see screenshots. Yes, "y" coord is way off, as in, the BrowserView y:0 is equivalent to BrowserWindow y:0 + height of Browser Window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must call BrowserWindow.addBrowserView() BEFORE calling BrowserView.setBounds() -- (see Update #8)